# Images not being displayed on iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I have a small iPhone app which works fine on iOS 4, but when i run it on iOS 3.2 or below none of the app images are displayed. At first, i thought it was because i was missing some high res images but if that was the case then the images still would have been displayed on iOS 3.2?

So, my question is: Why are my images being displayed fine on iOS4 but not at all on iOS 3.2 and below?

EDIT: This is how im loading the images atm (its in a UITableView):

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImage *chevronImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron"];
UIImageView *chevronImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:chevronImage];

[[cell imageView] setImage:cellImage];
[[cell textLabel] setText: [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell setAccessoryView:chevronImageView];
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you load the images? UIImage imageNamed? Have you checked that the case of the image names?

Comment: Some images are loaded in UIImage imagename in code and some are loaded in IB, but none of them work. The case is correct because the images work in iOS4.

Comment: When you say work on iOS4 is this on the device or on the simulator? And when testing for iOS3 are you a device? Have you checked if the images are copied in the bundle (open ipa and check) have you tried a clean and build for both iOS3 and 4.

Comment: I've tested on an iOS 4.2 device(iPhone) and the 4.0 - 4.2 simulator, all display the images fine. Also, tested on a 3.1 device(iPod touch) and the 3.2 iPad simulator, neither display the images at all. I can see the images are being copied, and i've tried a clean all targets then a build but still, no joy.

Comment: UIImage *chevronImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron"];
Do you try to add in the image extension in your code?

Comment: Aha! That was it, changing UIImage *chevronImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron"]; to UIImage *chevronImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron.png"]; worked. How stupid am i?  Thanks !!

Comment: As @arkchong mentions iOS 3 will need the extension (png/jpg) in the name. Good to know, never noticed it before but now I will always add the extension to the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem related to the filename extension in your call:

```
UIImage *chevronImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron"];
```

You could try to change this to:

```
UIImage *chevronImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron.png"];
```

I suspect that iOS 4+ "automagically" infers the images extension when you do not use them.